# How can you filter packets by content using native Linux tools such as netfilter?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp, netfilter

I am aware that you can use netfilter to filter out packets based on address, protocol, and other things.  My question is can you use netfilter (or some other native Linux utility) that will allow you to filter packets based on content.   The filtering should be done on the client side, which is running linux with root access.

For example (for purposes of this discussion), let's say I would like to DROP all incoming UDP packets that have the word "porn" in the body of the packet (assume no compression, no ssl, and we are only trying to catch packets with this word in ASCII/plain-text in body of packet).  Is there a way to create a iptable, netfilter, related rule to drop these incoming UDP packets?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the iptables string module to look for an string anywhere in the packet (including the headers).

For example, to filter the example you have pointed:

```
 iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m string --string "porn" --algo bm -j DROP
```

More info about this usefull module [here](https://wiztelsys.com/blog/iptables-string-matching-for-advanced-firewalling/).

Answer (score 2):

The [kpcre module](https://github.com/xnsystems/kpcre) allows of packet content filtering using **regular expressions**.

For example, to filter the example you have pointed:

```
    iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m string --string "/porn/i" --algo regex -j DROP
```

The string "/porn/i" denotes *case insensitive* "porn" string.